# Prototype JS find span and replace text

Tags: javascript, magento, prototypejs

I am struggling with this prototype.  Basically I am using Magentogo and it uses the prototype framework, on my products page there is a link to size guide, what I need to do is create a popup modal for this so the user remains on the page.

```
<span class="widget widget-cms-link"><a href="/size-guide" title="Size Guide">
  <span>Size Guide</span>
 </a>
</span>
```

What I need to do is find the span "widget widget-cms-link" and then replace the link with a button I can use to activate a modal popup.  I can do this in JQuery but it conflicts with Prototype.  Any one had experience in Prototype please?

Cheers

J

Comment: post your jquery code, it will help us understand better :)

Comment: All I do is $('.widget-cms-link span').html() and then replace the inner html.

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

```
​$$('.widget.widget-cms-link').each(function(el) {
    el.down('a').replace(new Element('button', {
        'class' : 'widget-button'        
    }).observe('click', function() {
        alert('you clicked on me');
    }).update('Your New Button'));
})​;​
```

Just remember that because `$$` returns an `Enumerable`, it can return multiples, therefore I am using the `each`. If you only want to reference one link, give it an id or ensure that there is only on of the `widget-cms-link`s on the page.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/LP6p4/)

Comment: Thank you very much when I put it in the page it doesnt work.  It might be a Magento issue.

Comment: I am getting this error in the console  SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: what happens if you try it in firebug console?

Comment: Seems you posted at the same time as me with the same idea. What happen if you just type ​`$$('.widget.widget-cms-link')` into the console?

Comment: @JohnJones, `Ctrl+Shift+I`, then click on console

Answer (score 0):

If you're more familiar with jQuery than Prototype, than you could try to use noConflict mode, and run your jQuery functions.

Just add jQuery.noConflict() at the end of your jQuery file (or insert this code in separate file and include it just after your main jQuery file).

After it's done, you should be able to use jQuery, just remember to use keyword `jQuery` for your jQuery functions, not `$`.